# I want to import images from SQLServer database to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, database

I have a 'Images' table which I created using SQL server management studio 17. I also have a 'Pictures' table in the MySQL. I want to first upload the pictures to the SQL server database using the Python GUI (tkinter). Then I want to get the pictures from SQL server as a blob in the MySQL database automatically. How do I get the data from SQLServer to MySQL? I tried ODBC but I found the tutorials to query from the SQL server to the MySQL database.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This question sounds challenging but unfortunately it lacks any clarity. What datatypes are you using? What are you expecting as an answer? As posted this is just too vague and too broad.

Comment: I am trying to upload JPG file using the python to the SQL server and get the image as the blob in the mySQL

Comment: Just explaining what you want to do again is not the same thing as providing enough details for others to help. Maybe look at replication?